# How to create a custom checkout page in Paypal for variable amount one time payments and recurring payments?

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal, checkout, paypal-subscriptions

When a user make a custom amount payment, I need to show a Paypal checkout page with different fields like tax, total amount etc. I want to add multiple fields like sales tax, total amount etc. How will I achieve it?

Also We have implemented PayPal subscription payment in our web application.

1. Can we add sales tax to the each Subscription payment ?
2. If we update the sales tax rate, Then is the new sales tax rate will be applicable to the existing subscribed users ? or is it only applicable for the new subscriptions ?

Answer (score 0):

For details see the [v2 Orders create](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) API reference, here is an example payload

```json
{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "260",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "200"
          },
          "shipping": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10"
          },
          "tax_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "50"
          }
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Name of Item #1 (can be viewed in the upper-right dropdown during payment approval)",
          "description": "Optional description; item details will also be in the completed paypal.com transaction view",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "100"
          },
          "quantity": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```